# How to create htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When a user is typing below urls

```
http://www.oldwebsite.de/schnitz_krippen.php
http://www.oldwebsite/holzrohlinge.php
http://www.oldwebsite/neuheiten.php
http://www.oldwebsite/impressum.php
```

I need these url redirect in to

```
http://www.newwebsite.de/impressum.php
```

How it's possible with htaccess? I don't need to redirect the whole website. because some links of old website need to show. eg:http://www.oldwebsite/main.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldwebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect all the calls to your virtualhost to the new website url:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php
```

If you want only certain urls to be redirected:

```
Redirect "/schnitz_krippen.php" "http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php"
Redirect "/holzrohlinge.php" "http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php"
Redirect "/neuheiten.php" "http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php"
Redirect "/impressum.php" "http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php"
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php [L]`   is this the full format?

Comment: While server htaccess do i need to edit newwebsite or oldwebsite?

Comment: You have to put that on the `.htaccess` file of your old website, and the file must be in its root folder

Comment: I updated the solution, the `[L]` optin should not be there

Comment: I have added above solution but problem is when I type http://www.oldwebsite/main.php it will also redirect to http://www.newwebsite.com/impressum.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
RewriteEngine on 
# Redirect to another domain: www.newwebsite.de.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newwebsite\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newwebsite.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: While server htaccess do i need to edit newwebsite or oldwebsite?

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to redirect the whole oldwebsite in to new website. I need to redirect only some links which is mentioned in my question. After using your solution the whole website is redirecting in to newwebsite.